# Can I generate DLL without exporting friend classes

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllexport

### Updated:

I created a project that can 100% reproduce the problem. 

**1. DLL Project**
I named this DLL project **TestDLL**

The most important codes:

AddC.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
class CTestDLL;
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//use AddC somewhere inside the DLL internally
class AddC{
private:
    string _fake_string_ = "_fake_string_";
    void _fake_method_();
public:
    void add2Result(CTestDLL* test);
};
```

AddC.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "AddC.h"
#include "TestDLL.h"


void AddC::_fake_method_()
{
    _fake_string_ = "_fake_string_in_fake_method_";
}

void AddC::add2Result(CTestDLL * test)
{
    test->result += 1;
}
```

TestDLL.h:

```cpp
#ifdef TESTDLL_EXPORTS
#define TESTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#include "AddC.h"

class TESTDLL_API CTestDLL {
public:
    CTestDLL(void);
    void test();
    int getResult();
private:
    friend class AddC;
private:
    AddC addc;
    int result=0;
};
```

TestDLL.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "TestDLL.h"

CTestDLL::CTestDLL(){
    result = 0;
    return;
}

void CTestDLL::test(){
    auto _this = this;
    addc.add2Result(_this);
}

int CTestDLL::getResult(){
    return this->result;
}
```

**2. SimpleTestApplication Project**

The TestApplication has only two code files.

dll.hpp:

```cpp
#pragma once
class AddC{};
class CTestDLL {
public:
    CTestDLL(void);
    void test();
    int getResult();
private:
    int result = 0;
    AddC addc;
};
```

app.cpp:

```cpp
#include "dll.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "TESTDLL.lib")

int main(){
    CTestDLL test;
    test.test();
    test.test();
    test.test();
    cout << test.getResult() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The testApplication compile and link successfully.

But,But.When the main function exits, the program throws an exception that the stack was corrupted.

**The key point is '*fake* string_' variable in AddC.
But I don't how to do.**

---

### Previous:

Like this on a dll project:

```cpp
class B;
class C;
class __declspec(dllexport) A{
private:
   friend class B;
   friend class C;
}
```

And I compiled the dll project;

Use .dll,.lib and the following header file on a simple console project:
dll.hpp:

```cpp
class __declspec(dllimport) A{
private:
   friend class B;
   friend class C;
}
```

The main func:

```cpp
#include "dll.hpp"
#pragma comment(lib, "dll.lib")
int main(){
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiled successfully.But the program threw an exception when running:
***Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted.***

Who can help me?

Comment: Is the DLL compiled for the same architecture as the application using it (_i.e._ 32-bit / 64-bit)? Are you certain that the one being loaded automatically is the one matching the lib you are linking against? If you remove the friend declarations and/or the forward-declarations of `B` and `C` entirely, does the problem go away?

Comment: @paddy The dll and the application compiled on the same architecture(32-bit). Remove the friend declarations and/or the forward-declarations of B and C entirely is still not working.

Comment: @paddy If remove the friend declarations entirely in dll project and application, the problem went away.But the Class B and C are necessary in Class A.

Comment: And so is this the _exact_ code you have? In other words, those classes are not defined anywhere? Are those names used by something outside the DLL (_i.e._ your program)? I get the feeling you may be omitting important information by pruning away stuff that you believe is unrelated. Please ensure that any code you show in the question will 100% reproduce the problem. If your program looks different to that, you should show what it actually looks like.

Comment: A `friend` declaration is something which concerns the compiler but neither the linker nor the executable at run-time. Therefore, I struggle to believe that not exporting incomplete classes `B` and `C` could become the direct reason for a corrupted stack. (Actually, I struggle to believe that you can export an incomplete class.) Is the exposed code the exact code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I'll keep saying this over and over. Don't export concrete classes from DLLs. Export factory functions that return interface pointers (pure virtual classes) to class instances.

Comment: @selbie DLL Hell.Which means I need to refactor the dll code? Oh my God!

Comment: @AlexF However, there are no warnings or errors when compiling the project. And if the type of '_fake_string_' variable in the AddC is changed to int, the application exits normally. Can you tell me why? Is malloc mem for AddC when '_fake_string_' 
size unknown?

Comment: @Jidcoo - It only takes a few minutes to have your concrete class inherit it's public methods from an interface class. And another few minutes to implement a factory function.  Also, I suspect your crash is because of compiler and run-time differences with the the std:: library. If your DLL exports functions that references C++ types instead of POV types,  you'll want to definitely hide these from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

@selbie's suggestion regarding the factory function / method creating is the cleanest way to go (would prevent you from ending in situations like this), and design-wise it makes the most sense, but it's not mandatory (after all there are lots of *.dll*s out there exporting classes).

What jumped into my eye, was the fact that (in both scenarios) a header file was present in the application that was (somewhat) duplicating the (main) one in the *.dll*. 
**Every *.dll* comes with its own header file(s), and those are the ones that should be used by its clients** (*app*s or other *dll*s). They are both maintained by the *dll* creators, and when updates come, they are both in *sync*. 
Doing otherwise is not scalable (each *app* creating its own header file version), makes no sense, and I don't know why would anyone do something like that.

With this in mind, I recreated the environment (both scenarios), doing things the right way, and **everything worked fine**, then I worked my way to your (wrong) way, trying to identify the culprit.

Example (numbered the 2 scenarios: *00* and *01*):

- *DllExport.h*:

  ```c
  #pragma once

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  if defined(DLL_STATIC)
  #    define DLL_EXPORT_API
  #  else
  #    if defined(DLL_EXPORTS)
  #      define DLL_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #    else
  #      define DLL_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #    endif
  #  endif
  #else
  #  define DLL_EXPORT_API
  #endif
  ```
- Scenario ***00***:

  - *AddC.hpp*:

    ```cpp
    #pragma once

    #include <string>

    using namespace std;


    class CTestDLL;

    //use AddC somewhere inside the DLL internally
    class AddC {
    private:
        string _fake_string_ = "_fake_string_";
        void _fake_method_();

    public:
        void add2Result(CTestDLL *pTest);
    };
    ```
  - *TestDLL.hpp*:

    ```cpp
    #pragma once

    #include <DllExport.h>

    #include <AddC.hpp>


    class DLL_EXPORT_API CTestDLL {

    public:
        CTestDLL();
        void test();
        int getResult();

    private:
        friend class AddC;

    private:
        AddC addc;
        int result = 0;
    };
    ```
  - ***dll***:

    - *AddC.cpp*:

      ```cpp
      #include "AddC.hpp"
      #include "TestDLL.hpp"


      void AddC::_fake_method_()
      {
          _fake_string_ = "_fake_string_in_fake_method_";
      }


      void AddC::add2Result(CTestDLL *pTest)
      {
          pTest->result += 1;
      }
      ```
    - *TestDLL.cpp*:

      ```cpp
      #define DLL_EXPORTS

      #include <TestDLL.hpp>


      CTestDLL::CTestDLL()
      {
          result = 0;
          return;
      }

      void CTestDLL::test()
      {
          auto _this = this;
          addc.add2Result(_this);
      }

      int CTestDLL::getResult()
      {
          return this->result;
      }
      ```
  - ***app***:

    - *dll.hpp*:

      ```cpp
      #pragma once

      #define _WRONG_INNER_CLASS
      #if defined(_WRONG_INNER_CLASS)
      class AddC {};
      #else
      #  include <AddC.hpp>
      #endif

      #define _WRONG_IMPORT_DIRECTIVE
      #if defined(_WRONG_IMPORT_DIRECTIVE)
      #  define CLASS_IMPORT_API
      #else
      #  define CLASS_IMPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
      #endif


      class CLASS_IMPORT_API CTestDLL {

      public:
          CTestDLL();
          void test();
          int getResult();

      private:
          int result = 0;
          AddC addc;
      };
      ```
    - *main.cpp*:

      ```cpp
      #include <iostream>

      #include <cstdio>

      #define _DUPLICATE_DLL_HEADER_FILE
      #if defined (_DUPLICATE_DLL_HEADER_FILE)
      #  include <dll.hpp>
      #else
      #  include <TestDll.hpp>
      #endif

      #pragma comment(lib, "dll.lib")

      using std::cout;
      using std::endl;


      int main()
      {
          CTestDLL test;
          test.test();
          test.test();
          test.test();
          cout << test.getResult() << endl;

          printf("Done.\n");
          return 0;
      }
      ```
- Scenario ***01***:

  - *dll.hpp*:

    ```cpp
    #pragma once

    #include <DllExport.h>


    class DLL_EXPORT_API A {
    private:
        friend class B;
        friend class C;
    };
    ```
  - **dll**:

    - *dll.cpp*:

      ```cpp
      #define DLL_EXPORTS

      class B;
      class C;

      #include <dll.hpp>
      ```
  - **app**:

    - *AppDll.hpp*:

      ```cpp
      #pragma once

      #define CLASS_IMPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)

      class CLASS_IMPORT_API A {
      private:
          friend class B;
          friend class C;
      };
      ```
    - *main.cpp*:

      ```cpp
      #include <cstdio>

      #define _DUPLICATE_DLL_HEADER_FILE
      #if defined (_DUPLICATE_DLL_HEADER_FILE)
      #  include "AppDll.hpp"
      #else
      #  include <dll.hpp>
      #endif

      #pragma comment(lib, "dll.lib")


      int main()
      {
          A a;

          printf("Done.\n");
          return 0;
      }
      ```

Project structure:

[image: Img0]

**Results**:

- Scenario *00*:

  There were 2 mistakes:

  - Class *AddC* redefinition
  - Missing import directive for *CTestDll*

  In *dll.hpp* there are 2 ***_WRONG**** macros. If both are commented, it will work
- Scenario *01*:

  I couldn't reproduce the crash (with / without *friend*s)

**Note**: Tested with *VStudio **2022*** and *MSSDK **10.0.22000.0***